# Circular Permutations With Identical Objects

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a closed form solution for Circular permutations of N objects of n1 are identical of one type, n2 are identical of another type and so on, such that n1+n2+n3+..... = N?

Answer (score 6):

This is a straightforward application of Pólya's theorem. The answer is the coefficient of $x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2}\dots$ in the cycle index of the cyclic group of order $N$, which is
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d | N} \phi(d) p_d^{N/d}.$$
Here $\phi$ is Euler's totient function and $p_d$ is the power sum symmetric function $x_1^d + x_2^d+\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any way we can prove this combinatorially?

Comment: What do you mean by combinatorially? Pólya's theorem is a special case of Burnside's lemma, which is proved by counting a set of ordered pairs in two different ways. The only part of the proof that you might call noncombinatorial is that the size of the orbit of a point under a finite group action is the index of the stabilizer of the point.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I suggest warmly the book
[Combinatorial species and tree-like structures](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=83odtWY4eogC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=combinatorial+species+and+tree-like+structures&ots=m-87VMAq30&sig=ATCbMxkTlzZ0dleFKfBayefCXK8#v=onepage&q=combinatorial%20species%20and%20tree-like%20structures&f=false)
by Bergeron, Labelle and Leroux.

Or the original article by A. Joyal "Une théorie combinatoire des séries formelles." Adv. in Math. 1981

Si tu n'y a pas access je te conseil de jeter un oeil à [Introduction to the Theory of Species of Structures](http://bergeron.math.uqam.ca/Site/bergeron_anglais_files/livre_combinatoire.pdf) disponible sur le web (lien clickable).

Dans le formalisme des espèces, ton problème est décrit par l'espèce des cycles $C$. Chacune des sources que je t'ai donné explique comment traduire cette description en séries génératrices, les preuves sont combinatoires.

Si tu veux un dénombrement étiqueté,
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(t) &= \log\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right) = t + \tfrac{1}{2}t^2+\tfrac{1}{3}t^3+... \\\
C(t_1+t_2+t_3+...) &= -\log\left(1-t_1-t_2-t_3-...\right)\\\
\end{aligned}
$$
La solution que tu cherche est,
$$
-\frac{\partial^{n_1}}{\partial t_1^{n_1}} ... \frac{\partial^{n_k}}{\partial t_1^{n_k}}\log\left(1-t_1-t_2-t_3-...\right)
$$
évalué en $t_1 = 0$, ..., $t_k= 0$, ...

Pour le dénombrement non-étiqueté c'est bien comme dit Ira.

Comment: J'aurais du noté $x_k$ à la place de $t_k$ et du coup $C(p_1)=\log(\frac{1}{1−p_1})$ pour être en ligne avec l'autre réponse. 
